# Creating a maven project with Spark Framework

Tags: scala, maven, apache-spark

I'm currently a new developer in Scala. I'm currently trying to set up a spark application using the standard IDE for scala which is Eclipse Juno.

I created a scala application and then set the scala library to be 2.10.6 to be able to use the spark framework. Afterwards, converted it to a Maven Project.  I modified afterwards the Pom.xml to add a dependency of the following:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0</version>
</dependency>*
```

The intellisense can detect the imported package properly. I can type in the syntaxes without any given error. I then ran the main class containing the simple apache spark code and upon running it, I receive an error which is the following:

**Error: Could not find or load main class Home**

The following is the setup for my [pom.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwE3p.jpg):

Comment: This is due to scala version. Select the proper version under project》properties 》scala interpreter... change the scala version  and try again.

Comment: How are you running the spark code?  You pom is also missing a bunch of things like the scala compiler and scala library.  Also note that Java 8 is not supported by scala 2.10.6.

Comment: There is no scala interpreter in the project settings . . .

Comment: do do i need to downgrade the my java version?? i'm running the spark code via just clicking the scala app file -> run as-> scala application